# How do I get the text of an element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I’m comparing a variable with text that needs to be found inside a child element:

```
var selectedTVshow = 'something';
$('.tvshow').on('click', function() {
  checkIfDuplicate(selectedTVshow);
})

function checkIfDuplicate(show) {
  $('.container__list-of-shows li').each(function() {
    var tvShowTitle = $(this).find('.container__list-of-shows__info__title').text;
    console.log(tvShowTitle);
    if (tvShowTitle === show)
        $('body').append('<p>true</p>');
      // return false
  })
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4Kh5S/1/

However, it’s not returning the text of that object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: text is a method. add parentheses after .text e.g .text()

Comment: Hey Alex, please don't forget to mark answers as correct :) I'm a fiend for Stack Overflow acceptance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `.text()` instead of `.text`

Comment: Not a problem! Happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code :

```
var selectedTVshow = 'something';
$('.tvshow').on('click', function() {
  checkIfDuplicate(selectedTVshow);
})

function checkIfDuplicate(show) {
  $('.container__list-of-shows').each(function() {

    var tvShowTitle = $(this).find('.container__list-of-shows__info__title').text();
   console.log(tvShowTitle)
    if (tvShowTitle === show)
        $('body').append('<p>true</p>');
      // return false
  })
}
```